# Android GeoJsonPoint nonstandard/BAD JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, geojson, point

How do I extract the proper JSON out of a GeoJsonPoint?

I want the following JSON:

```
"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[35.850607,76.734215]}
```

BUT 
what I'm getting is:

```
"location":"Point{\n coordinates=lat\/lng: (35.850607, -76.734215)\n}\n"
```

Here's my code:

```
JSONObject X = new JSONObject();
JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
JSONArray coords = new JSONArray();
try{
     X.put( "location", new GeoJsonPoint( new LatLng( 35.850607, -76.734215) ); );
}catch ( JSONException aE ){ aE.printStackTrace(); }

X.toString()
"location":"Point{\n coordinates=lat\/lng: (35.850607, -76.734215)\n}\n"
```

I can get what I want w/ the following:

```
JSONObject X = new JSONObject();
JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
JSONArray coords = new JSONArray();
try{
    coords.put( 35.850607  )
          .put( 76.734215  );
    location
        .put("type", "Point")
        .put( "coordinates", coords);

    X.put( .put( "location", location );

}catch ( JSONException aE ){ aE.printStackTrace(); }

X.toString()
"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[35.850607,76.734215]}
```

BUT I want to use the  ***GeoJsonPoint***  datatype.

Here's the standard:

```
Point
Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected coordinates, longitude, latitude for geographic coordinates):

  { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [100.0, 0.0] }
```

from: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#point

Wutz my problem? 
Am I misunderstanding the proper use of GeoJson vs. Json??
or Is Android GeoJson/ GeoJsonPoint nonstandard GeoJson??